# BLE bonding callback in iOS

Tags: ios, bluetooth, bluetooth-lowenergy

I am trying to connect with a slave that automatically asks to bond (PIN), the questions is, how can I tell if the bonding occurred and if it was successful?

I can't find any callbacks related to it in the documentation.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 3):

we had a similar issue earlier this year with hardware that shall connect to Android and iOS. Don't take this as an answer to your problem but rather as a sharing of experiences made.

If you also want to support Android and have contact to the BLE hardware's firmware developers, I would encurage you to not use the BLE bonded approach, because we ran into trouble on Android with it. Android devices use a wide range of different bluetooth chips and those make use of different approaches for bonding.
If you don't mind Android, here is how you could make it work at least for iOS:

You are able to read characteristics on iOS although you did not complete the bonding process yet. What you can do is registering for a notification/indication on a certain characteristic and get notified by the bluetooth peripheral, if the bonding was successful.

If you got no notification or indication characteristic in place and no control of the peripherals software, here is an alternate solution how you could at least know whether the bonding process worked or not:
Try reading an encrypted characteristic on the Bluetooth peripheral. On iOS this should not be possible, if you are not bonded. You could also try writing to a characteristic (but if I remember right, you should be able to do, if the characteristic was not secured).

Those are the experiences we made earlier this year Yoav, good luck with the bluetooth protocol. The way to success seems pretty long, but in the end you will be glad you made your way :-)

Comment: Thanks, I appreciate it. I do not have control over the BLE devices code, and I have no event for bonded and not even a encrypted characteristic to write because someone decided to make his own security protocol. We do have an android application as well, so I will pass your comment to my team. I think we're going to walk away from bonding though. It does seem weird though that they didn't bother adding a "peripheralDidBond" callback

Comment: @Lepidopteron, what problems did you have with Android bonding? The bonding is made on the host side by the Bluetooth stack and not by the chip itself.

Answer (score 1):

In my experience, the answer to the question of "how do we know if it bonded", is that

- it should show up under Settings -> Bluetooth -> My devices
- it should be returned from a call to CBCentralManager.retrievePeripherals
- and you should be able to reconnect with the returned CBPeripheral (via the CentralManager), even if the device is no longer advertising / in pairing mode.

This is what worked for me, anyway.

iOS only triggers bonding with the peripheral has set requires-encryption attributes on the characteristics, and you can still get a result from retrievePeripherals from just connecting to unencrypted characteristics (and not bonding). However, without bonding, reconnection attempts will fail (unless it continues to advertise).